# Query to consolidate multiple columns into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have a database query that queries for all products on our website.
It currently has 10,000 products and some of these products reside in 3 categories of products which the category information is stored in a tracking table.

This then means our queries return 3 instances of those products.

What Im wondering is. is it possible to query a database and return a single instance of these  products but place the category names into a single column like a list ?

Is this known as an aggregate function? or is this some sort of sub query that will consolidate the information into 1 column for use.

We are using MSSQL 2012

```
table products

id
product_name
display_name


table tracking
id
product_id
category_id
view_order


table categories
category_id
category_name


red tshirt with an id 1

categories
Mens Wear  with id of 1
Tshirts    with id of 2
clothing   with id of 3
```

what we would like as the output is

```
Product_name         category
Red Tshirt           Mens Wear,Tshirts,Clothing
```

instead of

```
Product_name         category 
Red Tshirt           Mens Wear
Red Tshirt           Tshirts
Red Tshirt           clothing
```

which is what we are getting now

Comment: It's diffucult to answer without knowing the table structures, relations between the tables and the desired output.

Comment: please post example of your data and example of the result you want to get

Comment: I hope I`ll see a GROUP_CONCAT in the next version of Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The following TSQL using the For XML trick to create a CSV field will do the trick

```
with combined (product_name, category) as (
  select product_name, category_name
  from
  products 
  inner join tracking on products.id = tracking.product_id
  inner join categories on categories.id = tracking.category_id
)
select
product_name,
 stuff((select distinct ',' + nullif(category,'')
 from combined t2 where t2.product_name = t1.product_name
 for XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') as category
 from combined t1
```